# Does a button have a WM_PAINT event?

Tags: c, winapi

If I have a Button as a child control on a Window, is the Button responsible for painting itself (i.e. does it handle the WM_PAINT event in its Window Procedure), or is the parent Window responsible for drawing its child controls?

Comment: The parent window wouldn't know how to do that, so how could this work?

Comment: @Damon This is what I thought, I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Each and every window has its own WM_PAINT event. You can delegate responsibility elsewhere, but only by intercepting the WM_PAINT message in the WindowProcedure of the window/control.

Comment: It depends on the button style. An owner-drawn button, for example ([`BS_OWNERDRAW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), will send a litany of messages to the parent window procedure regarding how the control is rendered. In particular a [WM_DRAWITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message will be sent to the parent window proc. No `WM_PAINT`, however, will be sent for said-style to the parent on behalf of the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WM_PAINT` is dispatched to all windows in order to paint themselves. The window procedure of the window receives the message and is then responsible for painting the window.

In the case of the button control, the window procedure registered by the `BUTTON` window class performs the painting.